# What Access token should I request ios / server

Tags: ios, facebook, token

I'm building an ios app that be integrated with facebook and was wondering what was the best way to get user access tokens that I'll be able to use on my server as well to run queries. I'm also a bit concerned about how long these tokens will last. Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/ios/ - log the user in using facebook's SDK, then send that token back to your server and you can use it from there.